# Chai-sorted throws assertion error for array of numbers

Tags: chai, cypress

I am trying to validate the values in a column to be in descending order.
All the values in the column are integers for percentage change.
It works all the times except when there is 100 for the first row.

```
 cy.get(grid)

    .find(column)
    .each(child => {
      cellVals.push(child.text());
    })
    .then(() => {
      chai.expect(cellVals).to.be.sorted({ descending: true });
    });
```

[ScreenShot with the values and the Error report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xr02E.png)

Not sure whats not working. Seems pretty straight forward and don't see a reason why it's failing. Appreciate any help.

Also, is there any other way to compare in Cypress without using chait-sorted ?

Comment: Cypress bundles the popular Chai assertion library out of box. Would request you to check this - https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/assertions.html#Chai

Comment: Was later able to figure out that it is actually doing a string comparison. Its not just the Chai Api, but the default behaviour for JS. Something like this solved the issue: expect(cellVals).to.be.deep.equal(sortedVals.map(v => String(v)));